# I want to make math operations with data from an MySQL table (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql, math, sum, multiplication

This is my question. The follwing is my current Table in MySQL.

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQpkx.jpg)

I have 2 INT columns **precio** (price) and **cant** (quantity) and I want to multiply these two tables. 
Example:
 10 * 8 = 80 
         10 * 6 = 60 
and so on, then I want to make a sum with all the results of the operations and print the total.

Does anyone know which MySQL commands I can use?
Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query would be like below : 
SELECT SUM( precio  * cant ) as total FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 1 = 1;

Comment: Are you sure the WHERE clause is necessary?  I don't believe it is.

Comment: Yes, you are right it is not necessary at all, but I have put just if you want to put your conditions there.